# Как передать массив в useState react?

Tags: reactjs

upd проблема все еще не решена, у кого есть идеи - подскажите, пожалуйста

Учу реакт второй день , так что не судите строго)

На данный момент, у меня есть рабочий код, который передает строку из компонента add в компонет app. Благополучно добавляется новый объект в app с одним полем name, но мне нужен еще и передать автора. Как это сделать? Я так понимаю, нужно передать уже что-то вроде этого {name: name, author: author}? А как это сделать?

Компонент app:

```
function addBook(name)
{
  setBooks
  (
    books.concat([
      {
        name: name
        //нужен еще и автор
      }
    ])
  )
}
```

Вот компонент addbook:

```
function AddBook({onCreate})
{
    function submitHandler(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault()

        if(name.trim)
        {
            onCreate(name)
            setValue('')
        }
    }

    const [name, setValue] = useState('')

    
    return(
    <form style={ { marginBottom: '1rem' } }onSubmit={submitHandler}>

        <input value={name} placeholder='Name' onChange={ event=>setValue(event.target.value)}/>
        //<input value={author} placeholder='Author' />

        <button type='submit'>Add book</button>
        <button style={{marginLeft: '1rem'}}>Cancel</button>
    </form>
    )
}

export default AddBook;
```

Comment: `setBooks(p => [...p, book])`. `setBook()` принимает либо значение, либо колбэк, если в новом используется новое

Comment: @entithat а в компонте addbook что надо делать? В usestate string же, всунуть туда объект у меня не вышло

Comment: В `AddBook` создайте стейт с автором и именем. И потом передавайте этот стейт как параметр - книжку

Comment: @entithat я вот тут споткнулся.

const [name, setValue] = useState('')

Что тут надо переделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нам надо в компоненте `AddBook` сохранять имя и автора книжки. Поэтому создадим стейт в виде объекта `{ name: '', author: '' }`. А дальше просто будем передавать его как параметр в родительский метод `addBook`.

Компонент `AddBook.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function AddBook({ onCreate }) {
  const [book, setBook] = useState({ name: "", author: "" });

  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (book.name !== '' && book.author !== '') {
      onCreate(book);
      setBook({ name: "", author: "" });
    }
  }

  return (
    <form style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        value={book.name}
        placeholder="Name"
        onChange={(e) => setBook((p) => ({ ...p, name: e.target.value }))}
      />
      <input
        value={book.author}
        placeholder="Author"
        onChange={(e) => setBook((p) => ({ ...p, author: e.target.value }))}
      />
      <button type="submit">Add book</button>
      <button style={{ marginLeft: "1rem" }}>Cancel</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Компонент `App.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import AddBook from './AddBook';

export default function App() {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  function addBook(book) {
    setBooks((p) => [...p, book]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <AddBook onCreate={addBook} />
      {books.map((book) => (
        <div>
          <p>
            {book.name} - {book.author}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Обвиняет эту строчку в том, что value null
-
 onChange={(e) => setBook((p) => ({ ...p, name: e.target.value }))}

Comment: @Игорь, хм. Странно. У меня работает.

Comment: Действительно странно. Я просто перекопировал код, тут негде особо что-то не так сделать

Comment: @Игорь, киньте где-то на pastebin, я гляну

Comment: https://pastebin.com/T40ep5Sc

Comment: И покажите ошибку еще

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: ошибка точно в месте, где инпут?

Comment: У Вас `removeBook` немного неправильно написан. Поменяйте на `setBooks(p => p.filter(...))`

Comment: <input
  50 |   value={book.name}
  51 |   placeholder="Name"
> 52 |   onChange={(e) => setBook((p) => ({ ...p, name: e.target.value }))}
     | ^  53 | />

ошибка на 52

Comment: @Игорь, честно, не могу понять что не так...

Comment: Вчера подобное было с angular, теперь время react. Спасибо за помощь В любом случае лучше, чем ничего

Comment: Я разобрался сам, переписал немного по другому.

Comment: отлично ...... :)